# Can someone tell me what this is?

Tags: part-identification, kia, optima

[image]It's on a 2015 Kia Optima.  Hanging down right behind the front bumper.  It had a metal bracket that looks broken.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3):

That will be the [ambient temperature sensor](https://www.kioptima.com/ambient_temperature_sensor-812.html).  It is used by the air conditioning system.

KIA’s description from the weblink -

**Kia Optima: Air Conditioning System / Ambient Temperature Sensor**

The ambient temperature sensor is located at the front of the condenser and detects ambient air temperature. It is a negative type thermistor; resistance will increase with lower temperature, and decrease with higher temperature.

The sensor output will be used for discharge temperature control, temperature regulation door control, blower motor level control, mix mode control and in-car humidity control.

If the ambient temperature is below 2.0°C (35.6°F), the A/C compressor will stop.

[image]

Comment: Would it also be the dashboard outside temp source, if the vehicle is so equipped?

Comment: Plain AC doesn't need it AFAIK, automatic climate control may use it. ECU also uses it for emissions purposes on new cars, I know for a reasonableness check for intake air temperature and as I understand it, they may use it to estimate cat temperatures on warm starts.

Comment: @user71659 the KIA webpage that I linked tells you exactly what it is for.

Comment: @wistlo. More than likely.